# Not able to read data from controller into the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In view

```
 <fieldset>
                         <legend>Projects:</legend>
                            <label>Total: {{projectsData.totalProjects}}</label> <br>
                            <label>Create: {{projectsData.createdProjects}}</label> <br>
                            <label>Open: {{projectsData.openProjects}}</label> <br>
                            <label>Completed: {{projectsData.completedProjects}}</label> <br>
                            <label>Accepted: {{projectsData.acceptedProjects}}</label> <br>



                    </fieldset>
```

In controller

```
    app.controller('dashboardConroller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        var userDashboardService = dashboardService($http);

        $scope.projectsData = [
{  
    "totalProjects": "20",
   "createdProjects":"2",
   "openProjects":"3",
   "completedProjects":"5",
   "acceptedProjects":"10"
}
];

    }])
```

In the view i am not getting anything, the data from the JSON is not getting displayed. I dont know why ?

Comment: It seems that `$scope.projectsData` should be `object` and not an `array`.

Comment: Is projectsData supposed to be a summary? I would put that in its own variable and only put project data in the object array. You can then use ng-repeat to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.projectsData` is array of object.

If you want to use array of obejct then you can do it using `[ng-repeat][1]`.

e.g.

```
<p ng-repeat="project in projectsData">
 <label>Total: {{project .totalProjects}}</label> <br> 
<label>Create: {{project .createdProjects}}</label> <br> 
<label>Open: {{project .openProjects}}</label> <br> 
<label>Completed: {{project .completedProjects}}</label> <br>
 <label>Accepted: {{project .acceptedProjects}}</label> <br
</p>
```

If you not using array of obejct then your object should be this

```
 $scope.projectsData =  {  
    "totalProjects": "20",
   "createdProjects":"2",
   "openProjects":"3",
   "completedProjects":"5",
   "acceptedProjects":"10"
};
```

So, your HTML will work with no change.

```
<label>Total: {{projectsData.totalProjects}}</label> <br> 
<label>Create: {{projectsData.createdProjects}}</label> <br>
<label>Open: {{projectsData.openProjects}}</label> <br>
<label>Completed: {{projectsData.completedProjects}}</label> <br>
<label>Accepted: {{projectsData.acceptedProjects}}</label> <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `projectsData` is an array of object.

You have to use index in order to access.

Try like this

```
 <label>Total: {{projectsData[0].totalProjects}}</label> <br>
<label>Create: {{projectsData[0].createdProjects}}</label> <br>
<label>Open: {{projectsData[0].openProjects}}</label> <br>
<label>Completed: {{projectsData[0].completedProjects}}</label> <br>
<label>Accepted: {{projectsData[0].acceptedProjects}}</label> <br>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/c1d0dtcs/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-repeat to show the data.Because you have array of object:

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in projectsData">{{x.totalProjects}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your `$scope.projectsData` is an array. Make it an object as below

```
$scope.projectsData = {  
   "totalProjects": "20",
   "createdProjects":"2",
   "openProjects":"3",
   "completedProjects":"5",
   "acceptedProjects":"10"
}
```

It will work as expected after this.